# A solid nickname regexp

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression to validate a nickname: 6 to 36 characters, it should contain at least one letter. Other allowed characters: 0-9 and underscores.

This is what I have now:

```
if(!preg_match('/^.*(?=\d{0,})(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,36}).*$/i', $value)){
 echo 'bad';
}
else{
 echo 'good';
}
```

This seems to work, but when a validate this strings for example:

11111111111a > is not valid, but it should
aaaaaaa!aaaa > is valid, but it shouldn't

Any ideas to make this regexp better?

Answer (score 4):

I would actually split your task into two regex:

1. to find out whether it's a valid word: `/^\w{6,36}$/i`
2. to find out whether it contains a letter `/[a-z]/i`

I think it's much simpler this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'/^(?=.*[a-z])\w{6,36}$/i'
```

---

Here are some of the problems with your original regex:

```
/^.*(?=\d{0,})(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,36}).*$/i
```

- `(?=\d{0,})`: What is this for??? This is always true and doesn't do anything!
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,})`: You don't need the `{1,}` part, you just need to find *one* letter, and `i` flag also allows you to omit `A-Z`
- `/^.*`: You're matching these outside of the lookaround; it should be inside
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,36}).*$`: this means that as long as there are between 6-36 `\w` characters, *everything else in the rest of the string* matches! The string can be 100 characters long mostly containing illegal characters and it will still match!

Comment: You can omit the `A-Z`, or the `i` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using two calls to preg_match as:

```
if( preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]{6,36}$/i',$input) && preg_match('/[a-z]/i',$input)) {
 // good
} else {
// bad
}
```

Comment: A bit late: it's a duplicate of SilentGhost's answer.